# How can I filter out specific email addresses?

Tags: mysql, sql, wildcard, sql-like

I am using MySQL to query a table of customer details called "clients", which includes a column for email addresses called "email". I would like to exclude all email addresses from gmail, hotmail and yahoo. I have tried writing the query (see below for my latest) but I cannot seem to get the use of NOT LIKE correct or find an alternative.

Can someone please help?

## MySQL Query:

```
SELECT      name, email

FROM        clients

WHERE       email NOT LIKE '%gmail%'
    OR  email NOT LIKE '%hotmail%'
    OR  email NOT LIKE '%yahoo%'
;
```

## End

P.S. I have searched for existing questions but no luck in finding the answer I need. Apologies if one already exists and I would appreciate you pointing me in the right direction if you find one. I'm a newbie to all of this, as I started learning SQL a few months ago for work.

Comment: For a query like that you'd want to use `AND`s not `OR`s

Comment: @Novocaine88 Please submit it as an answer, you are correct.

Answer (score 5):

You were nearly there, just replace the `OR`'s with `AND`s

```
SELECT name, email
FROM clients
WHERE email NOT LIKE '%gmail%' AND email NOT LIKE '%hotmail%' AND email NOT LIKE '%yahoo%';
```

By using `AND` it means that every condition needs to be met. Using just `OR` means that any condition *can* be true, but because you're also using `NOT LIKE` as well technically every row will match your conditions.

e.g. a gmail row matches the hotmail and yahoo rules individually and will therefore be returned in the results because of the `OR` as any rules can be matched.

Comment: That makes perfect sense and it works - thanks a lot!